# Use annonate to relabel x-axis in proc gchart

Tags: sas, gchart

Suppose I have a bar chart that has groups and subgroups, I wish to relabel the x-axis which have existing names for the groups.

How can I use annotate to relabel this x-axis?

Comment: Do you want to use annotate or are other solutions also applicable? How many entries are on the x-Axis and which kind of new labels do you want to introduce? There might be a solution by introducing a `format` on the x-variable.

Comment: I have the groups (midpoint variable) and there are 4 entries in each group. Now instead of labelling the midpoint variable on the x-axis, i wish to have them replaced by a different set of values, is there a way I can do that?